# AWS Glue ETL Integration with Spark and Scala

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-glue

I created a database called "glue-demo-db" and created a catalog for table "orders". Now, I am planning to write my own Scala script to execute ETL. The job is simple, read data from the glue-demo-db.orders table and write that as CSV into a S3 bucket. For some reason, 1) The diagram cannot be generated for Scala, and 2) The job keeps on running continuously without ending or creating the output file. Any help will be much appreciated.

Code:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.GlueContext
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.GlueArgParser
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.Job
import java.util.Calendar
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.from_json
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.Trigger
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

object ordersDataCapture {
  def main(sysArgs: Array[String]) {
    val spark: SparkContext = new SparkContext()
    val glueContext: GlueContext = new GlueContext(spark)
    val sparkSession: SparkSession = glueContext.getSparkSession

    // @params: [JOB_NAME]
    val args = GlueArgParser.getResolvedOptions(sysArgs, Seq("JOB_NAME").toArray)
    Job.init(args("JOB_NAME"), glueContext, args.asJava)

    // @type: DataSource
    // @args: [database = "glue-demo-db", table_name = "orders", redshift_tmp_dir = args["TempDir"], transformation_ctx = "<transformation_ctx>"]
    // @return: <output>
    // @inputs: []
    val read_data = glueContext.getCatalogSource(database = "glue-demo-db", tableName = "orders", redshiftTmpDir = args("TempDir"), transformationContext = <transformation_ctx>).getDynamicFrame()

    #Convert dynamic frame to data frame to use standard pyspark functions
    val sourceDF = read_data.toDF()
    sourceDF.printSchema()
    sourceDF.show(false)

    sourceDF.write                           // joined.write returns type DataFrameWriter
          .mode(SaveMode.Append)
          .format("csv")
          .save("s3://nvs-ordersdata/output")

    Job.commit()
  }
}
```

Comment: goto aws support option at. the top most right handside of aws page. they will see your execution id and details internally and they will suggest you chat phone mail options are there. its more relavent there than SO. its not debuggable code piece

Comment: Diagram is not generated as you are not applying any transformation after reading the data. You are just converting the dynamic frame to pyspark dataframe and saving it using pyspark write functionality instead of glue. For long running queries check your cloudwatch log and try to get the stacktrace from there.

Comment: AWS recently launched the spark scala,python to execute the program in local environment.
Please have a look and follow same. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-libraries.html#develop-local-scala